# Использование yajra datatables вместе с laravel-breeeze

Tags: html, ajax, laravel, datatable

я настроил yajra datatables, все успешно работает, но сейчас хочу реализовать это совместно с laravel-breeze, но у меня не получается этого сделать. Не выводятся данные таблицы, отображаются только заглавия столбцов, в чем может быть проблема?
Ниже я представил 2 листинга:

---

-в первом просто реализация yajra datatables (я не стал приводить роутинг и контроллеры, т.к. все работает, перестает работать только при изменении шаблона index.blade.php, поэтому я привожу только его, но если нужно что-то еще только скажите)

---

-моя попытка реализовать yajra datatables при помощи компонентов laravel-breeze

Также привел скрины до(1) и после(2)...
Листинг 1
Listing 1, all works.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Format Documents</title>

    {{--    bootstrap   --}}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {{-- jquery --}}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    {{--    datatables --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

    {{--    buttons--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/css/buttons.bootstrap5.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js"></script>


    {{--    select--}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

    <script src="{{asset('plugins/editor/js/dataTables.editor.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('plugins/editor/js/editor.bootstrap5.min.js')}}"></script>


</head>
<body>
<section style="padding-top: 60px;">
    <div class="container">
        {!! $dataTable->table(['id' => 'format-table'], true) !!}
    </div>
</section>
<script>
    $(function () {

        var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
            ajax: "/service/formats",
            table: "#format-table",
            display: "bootstrap",
            fields: [
                {label: "Formats name:", name: "name"},
            ]
        });

        $('#format-table').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
            editor.inline(this);
        });

        {{$dataTable->generateScripts()}}
    })

</script>

</body>
```

Листинг 2.

```
    <x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/css/buttons.bootstrap5.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.bootstrap.min.css">

    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Dashboard') }}
    </h2>
</x-slot>

<x-content-body>
    <section style="padding-top: 60px;">
        <div class="container">
            {!! $dataTable->table(['id' => 'format-table'], true) !!}
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.0/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.0/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('plugins/editor/js/dataTables.editor.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('plugins/editor/js/editor.bootstrap5.min.js')}}"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {

            var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
                ajax: "/service/formats",
                table: "#format-table",
                display: "bootstrap",
                fields: [
                    {label: "Наименование формата:", name: "name"},
                ]
            });

            $('#format-table').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
                editor.inline(this);
            });

            {{$dataTable->generateScripts()}}
        })

    </script>

</x-content-body>
</x-app-layout>
```

1
[image]
2
[image]